# jQuery Tooltip plugin 1.3 with ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm working with **jQuery 1.7.2** and **jQuery Tooltip plugin 1.3.**.
I have a bunch of divs with the class **customer**. Every div has an title attribute which contains the **customer ID**.
My goal is to load **dynamic data** with **AJAX** in a tooltip which shows up when a user moves his mouse over the div.

This is the code which I have now:

```
    jQuery('.customer').tooltip({
        delay: 0,
        showURL: false,
        bodyHandler: function() {
            return jQuery('<div>HERE I WANT TO SHOW SOME RELEVANT CUSTOMER DATA</div>').attr('src', this.src);
        }
    });
```

As you can see I do not have the required code to find the customer ID. I have been trying to add parameters in the `bodyHandler` function but this doesn't work.
Also the docs which are located at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip did not help me out..

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a post for the same. You may get some idea here-

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/265445/jQuery-tooltip-with-ajax-tooltip-datasource-with-g

Comment: Thank you, I've read the page, but the way that you are finding the IDs differs quite a lot from mine.. I've been trying some things with .closest('div).find() but I did not manage to grab the customer ID.

Answer (score 0):

you can use html 5 data-attributes to hold the customer id in the Container, then later you can retrive the customer id by using [Jquery data()](http://api.jquery.com/data)

```
<div class="customer" data-CustomerID="YourCustomerID" > asdfasdfasdf</div>
```

and the Jquery part

```
 jQuery('.customer').tooltip({
        delay: 0,
        showURL: false,
        bodyHandler: function() {

            alert($(this).data("CustomerID")); // will print your customerID, 
             // check in the console $(this) means, your current div wher you hovered it . 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm using data-CustomerID now. 
Unfortunately there are multiple divs with the customer class so I have to find the customer id for the current div..

Comment: @E.Clark try to check for $(this) in the body handler, as it will show the current id , n also updated answer

Comment: I've used jQuery(this), this leads to the following piece of code:
jQuery('.customer').tooltip({
 delay: 0,
 showURL: false,
 bodyHandler: function() {
     return jQuery('<div>'+jQuery(this).data('CustomerID')+'</div>').attr('src', this.src);
    }
});
It now shows undefined...

Comment: check in console. for what $(this) means., can you setup  for us . http://jsfiddle.net so that we can look on it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ChZQb/2/
I have manually added the js css for jQuery tooltip.. I can't get it to work..